# Realm slow on updating multiple objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my app the user can select multiple contacts in a collectionview. when he selects the property "isSelected" will me set to true and the collectionview refreshes the selected cell. Here I can recognize a small delay between selection and the highlighting of the cell. But in the next step I create a group with the selected contacts and in the end I set the property "isSelected" to false. This takes an non acceptable amount of time for 50 objects (5 seconds) and needs to be tuned.

Here is my code to unselect all the selected contacts:

```
for contact in self.selectedContacts {
            try! self.realm.write{
                contact.isSelected = false;
                self.realm.add(contact, update: true)
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to perform a batch-update at once?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try putting the for loop inside the write block:

```
try! self.realm.write {
    for contact in self.selectedContacts {
        contact.isSelected = false;
        self.realm.add(contact, update: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks! And how would you implement the selection to reduce the  highlighting delay?

Comment: That's hard to tell without seeing the actual code. Maybe you could another question for that (it's a different topic anyway)?

Comment: Moving the .for loop inside the .write, does the job a lot faster. But my realm file increased from 2.9mb up to 75.5mb. I didn´t changed anything at all. Any hint why this happened?

Comment: @Cilas Not without seeing your code ;-) Can you create a new question for that (including relevant code)?

Comment: @joern ... the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228149/realm-file-size

Answer (score 0):

You should add Toggle selection logic out side of write block. for speed up Realm updating process.

```
    for contact in self.selectedContacts {
        contact.isSelected = false;
    }
    try! self.realm.write{
        self.realm.add(self.selectedContacts, update: true)
    }
```