# iOS: Realm file is size going exponentially more than GBs

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm as persist store for swift based iOS application.

I have four tables with 6 columns each and each table is having 5k entries each table.(all are strings).This structure is reaching to 3GB.

what could be the issue it reaches 3GB?

Comment: Are you by any chance using the Realm browser while writing to Realm? There's a [known issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2412) related to that.

Comment: Do you use `DispatchQueue.async` and forgot to use `autoreleasepool {` while have lots of small transactions, maybe even 1 transaction / insert?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228149/unexpectedly-large-realm-file-size

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure that the data is actually 3 Gbytes or not. If it contains a lot of transaction version data, the file size will increase from the actual size. To do this, execute compaction or copy the Realm file.

Please see more details:
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limitations-file-size
​
At that time, if the file size does not change, 3 Gbytes of data is actually stored, so it can not be made smaller.
If the file size decreases, the file size is larger than the actual due to the transaction version pinning.

When I look at your code, you are using Realm in multithread, so there is a possibility to occur unintentional version pinning. Try to use autorelease pool to minimize the lifetime of Realm instance. Also, setting shouldComplatOnLaunch to periodically compact at startup can also help solve the problem.