# Does the # of objects added/updated in a writeTransaction affect file size inflation/version pinning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

**Context:**

I have 3 RLMObjects: ModelA, ModelB, ModelC. ModelA has a one-to-many relationship to ModelB using RLMArray, and ModelB has a one-to-many relationship to ModelC using RLMArray. I am trying to persist a variable amount of objects into Realm (using v3.3.1).

**Objective:**

I need to persist all of these objects in one write transaction. I am given a total 30 ModelAs, 3000 ModelBs and 18000 ModelCs.

**Test Scenario 1:**

I tried assembling all of these models and would essentially call

```
RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[defaultRealm writeTransaction: ^{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      for (ModelA *myModelA in arrayOfModelA)
      {
         [defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:myModelA];
      }
   }
}
```

This scenario would result in the Realm file size hitting roughly 19MB.

**Test Scenario 2:**

I disassembled each object into their own array and tried persisting each set in their own writeTransaction like so (This means I didn't create any relationships between the objects):

```
RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[defaultRealm writeTransaction: ^{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      for (ModelA *myModelA in arrayOfModelA)
      {
         [defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:myModelA];
      }
   }
}

[defaultRealm writeTransaction: ^{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      for (ModelB *myModelB in arrayOfModelB)
      {
         [defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:myModelB];
      }
   }
}

[defaultRealm writeTransaction: ^{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      for (ModelC *myModelC in arrayOfModelC)
      {
         [defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:myModelC];
      }
   }
 }
```

This resulted in a realm file size of roughly 9.4MB

**Question:**

Am I seeing such a significant difference in file size simply because of the fact that they're no longer connected to each other? Or is Realm suffering less from version pinning? Is there a difference between two scenarios? What is the recommended design pattern to minimize version pinning, while keeping as much concurrency as possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Unexpectedly large Realm file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228149/unexpectedly-large-realm-file-size), where @bdash from Realm provides an excellent insight into the reasons for what you might be seeing as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank you very much for linking that to me. It was very insightful. Could you kindly resubmit this as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Thank you again

Comment: I have posted that as a comment for a reason, there's no extra value in my comment compared to that answer and simply referring to another SO answer does not qualify for an answer and copying the content of that answer would be plagiarism. If you feel that answer solved your question completely and you want to show that it has an answer without having to copy the other answer, you can vote to close yours as a duplicate to the linked question. I didn't do that, since I felt there might be other specific reasons to your problem as well and just linked the question as a general starting point.

Comment: @DávidPásztor got it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpectedly large Realm file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228149/unexpectedly-large-realm-file-size)